# Notification after script has finished in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, windows-7-x64

I'm interested in any method that will notify me once this script has finished execution. It's doing a full load from one database to another and each time it executes, it loads a month of data. Upon completion, I need to start it again after updating a control table to load the next month. The execution time varies due significantly due to varying amounts of data and varying available Oracle resources so simply setting a timer leads to unnecessary checking or lost potential load time.

```
BEGIN
  PKG_PACKAGENAME.PROCEDURENAME;  
END;
```

These are my ideas but I don't know what's actually possible to implement without significant external dependencies. The simplest method will be preferred for now. Anything similar is probably also be OK if it can be run within a secure corporate environment. I would prefer not to have to modify the package or procedure contents.

- Emit an audible notification
- Bring the SQL Developer Window to the front
- Perform a http request that launches an IFTTT app to send a push notification
- Run a python script which performs the http request

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER + email notification: https://jameshuangsj.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/how-to-send-email-notifications-from-dbms_scheduler-jobs/ or https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/scheduler-enhancements-11gr2#email_notification

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I do plan to use DBMS Scheduler for the incremental load, but was going to do this initial load manually since I anyways need to do quality checks along after loading each month. I don't yet have experience with DBMS Scheduler, so is there another solution that would be even easier, though likely less professional?

Answer (score 5):

> Bring the SQL Developer Window to the front

*Really* quick and dirty; add an `accept` to your script after the anonymous block that calls your procedure:

```
BEGIN
  PKG_PACKAGENAME.PROCEDURENAME;  
END;
/

accept dummy prompt "Script has finished, just press enter"
```

and run as a script (F5). When the block finishes the substitution variable prompt

[image: SQL Developer accept prompt]

steals focus; when you click OK or hit enter (or cancel - it doesn't matter what you do) the main SQL Developer window comes to the front.

Comment: Thanks very much, but this is not yet working for me.`BEGIN
  null  ;  
END;

accept dummy prompt "Script has finished, just press enter"`. I get an error `ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ACCEPT" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`

Comment: You need a slash to terminate the block, before the client `accept` command.

Comment: Running as a script. The version information follows. 12.2.0.14.48 seems to be the IDE version for comparison to your 18.4. I cannot update this on my work computer. Sorry that I didn't include this information before.

`About
-----

Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1.14
 Version 4.0.1.14
Build MAIN-14.48

IDE Version: 12.1.3.2.41.140207.1351
Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 12.2.0.14.48

Version
-------

Component Version
========= =======
Oracle IDE 4.0.1.14.48
Java(TM) Platform 1.8.0_161`

Comment: By the way, how can I format these SO comments more nicely and on multiple lines?

Comment: @Bobby - this should work in most versions, I think. You can't format comments really, they aren't intended for that much info (you can edit into the question if necessary, but I think you just need to add the slash anyway - I've edited my answer to show that).

Answer (score 1):

> Emit an audible notification

```
chr(7) will produce a beep in SQL*Plus, at least on Windows:Use it after your procedure run

SQL> select chr(7) from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll keep this in mind but I’m not using SQLPlus for this particular task.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running SQL Developer on Windows, use Powershell to instantiate a COM object which can speak:

```
begin
   dbms_lock.sleep(3);
end;
/

host powershell -c $sapi = new-object -comObject sapi.spVoice ; $sapi.speak('The script has finished')
```